# Entity Framework code first, isn't creating the database

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Here's an overview of how my solution looks:

[image]

Here's my PizzaSoftwareData class:

```
namespace PizzaSoftware.Data
{
    public class PizzaSoftwareData : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```

According to an example on Scott Guthrie's blog, you have to run this code at the beginning of the application in order to create/update the database schema.

```
Database.SetInitializer<PizzaSoftwareData>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PizzaSoftwareData>());
```

I'm running that line of code from Program.cs in PizzaSoftware.UI.

```
namespace PizzaSoftware.UI
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Database.SetInitializer<PizzaSoftwareData>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PizzaSoftwareData>());
            Application.Run(new LoginForm());
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me why the database isn't having the tables created?

Here's the connection string in my App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PizzaSoftwareData"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SaharaPizza;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
         providerName="System.Data.Sql" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Initializer is executed when you need to access the database. If you want to create database on application start either use:

```
context.Database.Initialize(true);
```

Or don't use initializer and call:

```
context.Database.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Comment: where would this line go?

Comment: @mmcrae: To initialization of the application. It depends on application type.

Comment: In my case somehow Database.Initialize(true) throws exception: Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.

Database.CreateIfNotExists() - works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of putting this code into main method:

```
Database.SetInitializer<PizzaSoftwareData>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PizzaSoftwareData>());
```

Put it into DBContext:

```
namespace PizzaSoftware.Data
{
public class PizzaSoftwareData : DbContext
{
        public PizzaSoftwareData()
        : base("name=PizzaSoftwareData")
        {
        Database.SetInitializer<PizzaSoftwareData>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<PizzaSoftwareData>());
        }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
}
```