# Create database in App_Start

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an solution with 2 projects, one domain class and one webUI.

In the domain class I have 2 models, a db context and a databas initializer.

List.cs:

```
namespace Todo.Domain
{
    public class List
    {
        public int ListID { get; set; }
        public string Day { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Task.cs:

```
namespace Todo.Domain
{
    public class Task
    {
        public int TaskID { get; set; }
        public int ListID { get; set; }
        public string TodoTask { get; set; }
    }
}
```

EFDbContext.cs:

```
namespace Todo.Domain
{
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EFDbContext() : base("TodoList") { }

        public DbSet<List> Lists { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Initializer:

```
namespace Todo.Domain
{
    public class TodoDbInit : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFDbContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(EFDbContext context)
        {
            var list = new List<List>
            {
                new List { Day="Måndag" }
            };
            list.ForEach(s => context.Lists.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();


            var task = new List<Task>
            {
                new Task { TodoTask="Fisk" }
            };

            task.ForEach(s => context.Tasks.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when I start my application, I want the database to be created. I have placed a setInitializer Global.asax:

```
namespace Todo.WebUI
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new TodoDbInit());
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my application, the database Is not created. I don't know why. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I'm wondering why you want to create a database every time your application starts. Wouldn't it make sense to keep it in memory?

Comment: Do you have anything that is actually making a call to the database? The db should be created on the first call.

Comment: @maniak1982: And how canI create the database just once?

Comment: @Cal279: What do you mean? Im making a call to the database In the initializer?

Comment: @Bryan - Yes, but in order for the initializer to be called you need a reason to create the database. And that will be your first call (select) on the database. Try doing a select on the first controller action (e.g. home/index) and see what happens.

Comment: @Cal279: So I must get rows from the database before It can be created?

Comment: @Bryan - yes, you need to 'touch' the database. I know it seems odd, but it is just a lazy init. You decide when the database needs to be created. Btw DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges will create the db only once if the model remains unchanged.

Comment: @Cal279: That don't seem right. In the tutorials I have read, they only insert data to (seed). No need to select the database.

Comment: @Bryan: The initializer is only used when you need access to the database. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414130/entity-framework-code-first-isnt-creating-the-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make a call against your database in one of your controllers in order for it to be created (creation is on-demand). If you wish to manually create the database on application start see the answer posted here: [Entity Framework code first, isn't creating the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414130/entity-framework-code-first-isnt-creating-the-database)

The following code is only setting the initializer that you wish to use against your database.

```
Database.SetInitializer(new TodoDbInit());
```

In order for it to actually be used you will need to create and access entities of your db context.

Comment: No. An initializer is for database creation and seeding.

Comment: Aha.. Now I get It. The Initializer Is fired when I trying to work with a database?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I will add clarification to my answer.