# Create Tables with EntityFramework using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, create-table

Create an empty database called "Lesson Authentication", using MySQL Workbench in linux Mint.

When I try to save my actions I get this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0q9f.jpg)

Here is my tiny project
[My Repository](https://github.com/lukasztomalczyk/Lesson_Authentication/tree/master/Authentication)

Comment: Please add the code and your exception into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the inner exception showing that the table `Users` doesnt exist.

You need to create the table Users before trying to insert any data.

For EF, Please refer to this question: [Entity Framework code first, isn't creating the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414130/entity-framework-code-first-isnt-creating-the-database)

Comment: But i shouldn't create manual table. Entity should do this for me, yes? I have dbset<user> Users . That is the correct name I want to have. Or I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your error clearly mentions the Table "LessonAuthentication.Users" doesnt exist......

Create a table with name 'LessonAuthentication.Users' and load your data into the table.

Comment: Or Maybe I need to put name "lessonAuthentication.user" in OnmodelCreating where I have  entity<user>().toTable("") ?

Comment: @LukaszTomalczyk 'LessonAuthentication.Users' itself is the total table name, I would try creating with that name....