# The underlying provider failed on Open on Windows XP but not Windows 7 - solved by browsing the DTC transaction list?

Tags: entity-framework-5, msdtc

I install my EF5 winforms application using Click Once.

When I installed on a Windows 7 virtual computer it worked correctly, however when I installed on a Windows XP virtual computer I got an "underlying provider failed on open" error.

I consulted [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open)  and decided to look at the Distributed Transaction Coordinator in component services on the XP computer..

I only viewed things in component services, by expanding the tree.
Now my application works, and I don't understand why it didn't or why it is fixed.
Can anyone explain this to me?