# Making EntityFramework Connection String dynamic

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, connection-string

I'm using this code for connect to my database over the network :

```
// Specify the provider name, server and database.
            string providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
            string serverName = "VENUS-PC";
            string databaseName = "Cheque";

            // Initialize the connection string builder for the
            // underlying provider.
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder =
                new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            // Set the properties for the data source.
            sqlBuilder.DataSource = serverName;
            sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = databaseName;
            //sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
            sqlBuilder.UserID = "sa";
            sqlBuilder.Password = "123";
            sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;
            // Build the SqlConnection connection string.
            string providerString = sqlBuilder.ToString();

            // Initialize the EntityConnectionStringBuilder.
            EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
                new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

            //Set the provider name.
            entityBuilder.Provider = providerName;

            // Set the provider-specific connection string.
            entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = providerString;

            // Set the Metadata location.
            entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Cheque.csdl|
                            res://*/Cheque.ssdl|
                            res://*/Cheque.msl";
            //Console.WriteLine(entityBuilder.ToString());
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(entityBuilder.ToString());

            using (EntityConnection conn =
                new EntityConnection(entityBuilder.ToString()))
            {
                conn.Open();
                //Console.WriteLine("Just testing the connection.");
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Connection is Ok");
                conn.Close();
            }
```

But this exception Thrown : The underlying provider failed on open.Login Failed for user 'sa'.
And I test the user name ,password ,server name and database name in Sql Server Managment Studio and it's working.
How can i fix my code?

Comment: Look at the answers on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2475008/861716) question.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static string GetConStrSQL()
{
    string connectionString = new System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        Metadata = "res://*",
        Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
        ProviderConnectionString = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            InitialCatalog = "Name Of The Database",
            DataSource = @"ServerNameHere\SQLEXPRESS",
            IntegratedSecurity = false,
            UserID = "sa",               
            Password = "your_password_here",  
        }.ConnectionString
    }.ConnectionString;

    return connectionString;
}
```

and in the creation of the context :

```
YouEFContext ctx = new YouEFContext(GetConStrSQL());
```

Comment: it's always only 1 damn line: `Metadata = "res://*",` missing :D thank you mate! have an upvote