# Having trouble setting up Entity Framework connection string in web.config for dev, qa, & prod

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, web-config, linq-to-entities

I inherited an old vs.net 2010 WCF webservice project to make a fix to. It has the following connectionString settings in its web.config, to differentiate between dev, qa, & production & I'm having trouble connecting to them when trying to debug & hoping someone can help:

```
  <connectionStrings>    
     <add name="OrderDataContextContainer.Development" connectionString="metadata=res://<conn string here>" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
     <add name="OrderDataContextContainer.QA" connectionString="metadata=res://<conn string here>" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
     <add name="OrderDataContextContainer.Production" connectionString="metadata=res://<conn string here>" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
 </connectionStrings>
```

The code I added, makes a db connection via the following "using" statement:

```
using (OrderDataContextContainer db = new OrderDataContextContainer())
 {
      //my code fix here
 }
```

If I add the following web.config connection to the list of connectionStrings, it connects fine (i.e. no "Development", "QA", or "Production" appended):

```
<add name="OrderDataContextContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://<conn string here>" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

However, I can't do it like this because my company requires separate dev, qa, & prod strings for when I send this fix to the QA team for testing.  If I don't include the above connection, I receive the following error on that "using" statement:

> The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.

Before running the project, I created "Development", "QA", & "Production" configs in my vs.net Configuration Manager & set it to "Development" but no luck.

Any idea how I can get my application to connect via the earlier mentioned connection strings?

Comment: maybe this [article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811305/web-config-debug-release) can help you.   you need to add web.QA.Config and web.Production.config. when you start publish, you can choose different profile(web.config), and then can transform your connection string.

Comment: Transforms are the way to go, but another option is [connection string builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065361/making-entityframework-connection-string-dynamic) if you want to do it in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `EF` always searches for the same connection string in the `.config` file. The name is defined in the `EF` designer and usually has the same name as the context class.

What you can do, is use `web.config` transformations, on how to do it in your project: [How to: Transform Web.config When Deploying a Web Application Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx)