# EF: The underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure

In production I have started getting this error all across my app:

```
The underlying provider failed on Open
```

As far as I could tell, I'm not getting this error when testing the app locally (at least I could not get it no matter what I did). I'm using Azure SQL server and here is my connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=myserver.windows.net,1433;Database=mydb;User ID=username;Password=password;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Here is one of methods where I'm getting error:

```
public IEnumerable<Country> GetCountries()
{
        List<Country> countries;
        using (var databaseContext = new Database())
        {
            countries = databaseContext.Countries.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList();
        }

        return countries;
}
```

Also I want to stress out that error is not happening all the time, it happens kinda randomly. This started to happen today, I have not changed this code, nor connection sting, nor database settings, but (!) I have refactored some methods from synchronous to asynchronous - I don't know this is somehow connected to this particular problem.

Also as far as I could tell this is only happening in ASP.net Web API project, but not in ASP:net MVC project (they share same service layer and call same methods from service)

And finally here is Pastebin link to whole stack trace (I won't paste it here because it is too big): [link](http://pastebin.com/qwb1w8q9)

Comment: Is it random or is it always linked to an async function (like GetUsaStates() )? If so, I expect a new thread does not have access to the EF context created on the start thread

Answer (score 3):

Please see this post: [Error 'The underlying provider failed on Open'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open).

The excerpt from the post that should resolve your issue is below:

> Changing my code to the following fixed it:

```
using (DatabaseEntities context = new DatabaseEntities())
{
    context.Connection.Open();
    // the rest
}
```

Comment: So I have to add this piece of code every time I initialize DB Context ?

Comment: And one more thing how why this happened out of blue ? As I said I haven't changed anything in my code

Answer (score 0):

Add connection string to your dbcontext constructor like `

```
public YourDbContext()
          :base(name="YourDbContext")
{
this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=****;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=****;Password=****";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while testing in Azure. In my case, I forgot to update the password in the application web.config. Post updating its working fine for me.