# How to write connectionString in App.config file using EF5 Code First Approach

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating WPF application using VS2013 Ultimate in which I want to create local database in Visual Studio. Here is sample connectionString which I am trying to write

ConnectionString in App.config file

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="RoznamchaContext" 
     connectionString="Server=.;database=sample;integrated security=true;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Context Class is here

```
class RoznamchaContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Admin> Admins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Task_Tag> Task_Tags { get; set; }

    public RoznamchaContext() : base("RoznamchaContext")
    { }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

This is my main class where I have a button, and when I press the button it gave me an exception shown in an image and button click-event is also given below.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<RoznamchaContext>(null);
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static int count = 0;

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RoznamchaContext context = new RoznamchaContext();
            context.Tags.Add(new Models.Tag { PK_Tag = count, Name = "Tag" + count });
            context.SaveChanges();
            count++;
            btn.Content = count.ToString();
        }catch(Exception ex)
        { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); }
    }
}
```

This image shows exception thrown by click-event named "btn_Click"
[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at this http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string is almost right. If you are using Entity framework you should also add [`providerName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/cc716756(v=vs.100).aspx) to your configuration:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="RoznamchaContext" 
       connectionString="Server=.;database=sample;integrated security=true;"
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Now you can use connection string name as a parameter of [`DbContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx):

```
class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public YourContext() 
        : base("RoznamchaContext")
    { }
}
```

You can also use convention over configuration when you named your connection string with the same name as your data context. Then you can use default `DbContext` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbContext.) (without parameters):

```
class RoznamchaContext : DbContext
{
}

<add name="RoznamchaContext" 
     connectionString="Server=.;database=sample;integrated security=true;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**UPDATE**

The other solution is to specify database initializer on the app Startup:

```
// add next line to the Run() method or Main method or other initialization method
Database.SetInitializer<RoznamchaContext>(null);
```

Comment: I have made changes according to your suggested code. please go through the question again now I updated it with details.

Comment: Thank you Vadim, Thank you so much. errors are vanishing with the creation of new errors ;-)    --- Now I have added Database.SetInitializer<RoznamchaContext>(null); in my MainWindow class constructor and having the error, please look at the updated question

Comment: exception comes when it submits the SaveChanges() method

Comment: @WASIF it's more generic problem. There is a detailed answer for your current problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open
 The short way is to try add `context.Connection.Open();` to your code.
The other one solution is to change some security setting like in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/126919/Solution-for-The-underlying-provider-failed-on-Ope

Comment: One thing I correct through these provided links is I was using "System.Data.SqlClient" then I made change to "System.Data.EntityClient". Now it is saying "keyword not supported 'server' "

Comment: Nooooo EntityClient used with EDM. Why are you changed it? Is there an error with SqlClient and Database.SetInitializer?