# ASP.Net MVC 4 - Connection Issue SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database from my ASP.Net MVC 4 application.

The connection string I have is:

```
<add name="EmployeeContext" 
     connectionString="server=DEVELOPER-PC; database=Sample; integrated security=SSPI" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

The error message I get is this:

> The underlying provider failed on Open.

To try and fix this issue added this piece of code into my connection string in VB `user id=js;password=jess1;` but to no avail.

Another site said to add my main computer user to SQL and this didnt work either.

My model class:

```
public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
    Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(x => x.EmployeeId == id);

    return View(employee);
}
```

**EDIT**

I also have this model in my application

```
namespace Department_Employee.Models
{
    [Table("tblEmployee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can anybody see where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you use SqlConnection object to make sure you can reach db without EF?

Comment: I am following a tutorial and this wasn't included. Can you explain where this should be and I will be happy to answer.

Comment: This should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/mssql-error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open

Comment: @Yogi I found the article before posting have tried but to no avial.

Comment: Please check your SQL Server Login type, Mixed Mode or Windows Authentication, if your type Mixed Mod then set id and password from connectionstring.

Comment: @TerrorTot38 By following [this link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection) you can make sure your Connectionstring is correct and database is running, Then, you can think about the EF problems.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this,

```
<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="Data Source=DEVELOPER-PC; database=Sample; User ID=username;Password=password";MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```