# Open: underlying provider failed on Open

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

I'm facing an issue that I've never encoutered before using Entity Framemork with MySQL connector.
I have the simple method core below:

```
ps_manufacturer manufacturer = null;
using (var context = new afflelou_storeEntities())
{
       var manufacturerList = context.ps_manufacturer.Where(m => m.id_AA_manufacturer == anId).ToList();
       if (manufacturerList.Count > 0)
       {
             manufacturer = manufacturerList.ElementAt(0);
       }
}
return manufacturer;
```

There is no data in database, so it should returns null. But instead, it throws me that error:

**Open: underlying provider failed on Open**

I've tried to use **firstOrDefault** but nothing works...
I was thinking that it's a database connection error, but I'm always using a **using** from my database connexions, so it never happens to have a non closed connexion. 
Someone has already faced that issue ?

Comment: StackOverflow is an English community, please rewrite your title in English.

Comment: Looks like the error is rather in your connection string and has nothing to do with your provided code. Using the wrong provider perhaps (.i.e MySQL database but using SQL Client provider)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MSSQL Error 'The underlying provider failed on Open'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/mssql-error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open)

Comment: @LocEngineer, a request is made just before on he same context and it works, so it doesn't come from the connexion string...

Comment: @Nasreddine thanks, but it's a Windows service program so nothing to do with IIS, thanks anyway, could be a solution

Comment: Well, could it be caused by that previous "request" then? maybe the error is there?

Comment: @HubertSolecki Have you tried adding the `context.Connection.Open();` line? Also, you should post your connection string (after replacing the username/password of course)

Comment: Which EF version? If you use EF6 you also have to use a EF6 compatible provider

Answer (score 1):

Definitely is a issue with your string connection, check it! If your credentials are right, so check doing ping to database server.