# The underlying provider failed on Open - entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

My entity framework application is not working, every time I start the application I receive :

> " The underlying provider failed on Open" excpetion. the inner exception is "server is unreachable"...

I'm using a local sql server and the `ConnectionString` is correct.(Already tested it in a small console application)

The connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="Programmeren5Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NinjaDataModel.csdl|res://*/NinjaDataModel.ssdl|res://*/NinjaDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\DEVELOPMENT;initial catalog=Programmeren5;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Here is the part that throws the exception:

```
var b = new List<Ninja>();
using (var context = new Programmeren5Entities())
{
    b = context.Ninja.ToList();
}
return b;
```

What could be the reason it doesn't work? The database also has the right format and does have all the columns. I also tried the DTC config solution and checked if the SQL service was running.

Comment: Did you check with SQL Authentication ?

Answer (score 0):

try this with SQL Authentication

```
<add name="Programmeren5Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*    
NinjaDataModel.csdl|res://*/NinjaDataModel.ssdl|res:
//*/NinjaDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection 
string=&quot;data source=.\DEVELOPMENT;initial catalog=Programmeren5; persist 
security info=True;user id=sa; password=****; multipleactiveresultsets=True;
App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

[MSSQL Error 'The underlying provider failed on Open'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/mssql-error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open)

Comment: nope, that doesn't work either :( I already tried the solutions in that thread but no succes

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/mssql-error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open