# Entity Framework error: "The underlying provider failed on Open" after SQL Server upgrade

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, connection-string

I have an application using Entity Framework that worked fine for years. The other day however, our IT team upgraded our SQL Server from 2005 (or it may have been 2008, I'm not sure) to SQL Server 2016. After this upgrade, we started getting this error:

> The underlying provider failed on Open

Any idea why this SQL Server upgrade may have caused this error & how I can fix it?

Here's my connection string if it helps:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyCompanyDataContext" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.MyCompanyDataAccess.Model.MyCompanyDataContext.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.MyCompanyDataAccess.Model.MyCompanyDataContext.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.MyCompanyDataAccess.Model.MyCompanyDataContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=OurDBServer01;initial catalog=OurDB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="AnotherDbDataContextContainer" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.Model.AnotherDbDataContext.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.Model.AnotherDbDataContext.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.Model.AnotherDbDataContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=OurOtherDbServer01;initial catalog=OurOtherDb;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Thanks

Comment: Inner exception, please!

Comment: Was the database upgrade on the same server that you had before?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475008/mssql-error-the-underlying-provider-failed-on-open various possible causes. But I noticed you use integrated security. Does your user exist in new server.