# Transactions with EF

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures, commit

I have 2 questions :

i) How can put this code in a **transaction** ?

With ObjectContext in EF, I use ExecuteStoreQuery() method to start some stored procedure. I have a block of code like this :

```
{
    foreach(...)
    {
     objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery( @"INSERT MyProcedure (arg1, arg2) VALUES                                 ({0}, {1});", ...);
    }
     // ...
     objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery( @"INSERT MyProcedure2 (arg1, arg2) VALUES                                 ({0}, {1});", ...);    
 }
```

ii) Is possible to commit **at the same time** `ExecuteStoreQuery()` calls with object context changes with `SaveChanges()` ?

My object context is changing in my code. At the end, I have to do a `SaveChanges()` to commit in the database. I'd like to commit in a same transaction the update of my objectContext data and all `ExecuteStoreQuery`. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Entity Framework: Using transactions and rollbacks... Possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452129/entity-framework-using-transactions-and-rollbacks-possible)